# How to read temperature from multiple DS18B20 faster?

Tags: sensors, temperature-sensor

I am writing an Arduino sketch to read temp data from multiple DS18B20 sensors and then write it to serial. The problem is, as I am connecting more sensors, the delay between my temp data is written to a serial increases (like 100ms for 1 sensor and 1s for 4 sensors). Can I somehow improve my sketch to read it faster?

Here is the sketch I am using:
(I am using DallasTemperature to simplify it all)

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 10
#define TEMPERATURE_PRECISION 8
#define BAUD_RATE 9600

// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices (not just Maxim/Dallas temperature ICs)
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature. 
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

// arrays to hold device addresses
DeviceAddress devices[10];
int devicesFound = 0;

void setup(void)
{
  // start serial port
  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
  //Serial.println("Dallas Temperature IC Control Library Demo");

  // Start up the library
  sensors.begin();

  // locate devices on the bus
  Serial.print("Locating devices...");
  Serial.print("Found ");
  Serial.print(sensors.getDeviceCount(), DEC);
  Serial.println(" devices.");

  devicesFound = sensors.getDeviceCount();  

  // report parasite power requirements
  Serial.print("Parasite power is: "); 
  if (sensors.isParasitePowerMode()) Serial.println("ON");
  else Serial.println("OFF");

  for (int i = 0; i < devicesFound; i++)
    if (!sensors.getAddress(devices[i], i)) 
      Serial.println("Unable to find address for Device" + i); 

  // show the addresses we found on the bus
  for (int i = 0; i < devicesFound; i++)
  {    
    Serial.print("Device " + (String)i + " Address: ");
    printAddress(devices[i]);
    Serial.println();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < devicesFound; i++)
    sensors.setResolution(devices[i], TEMPERATURE_PRECISION);
}

// function to print a device address
void printAddress(DeviceAddress deviceAddress)
{
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    // zero pad the address if necessary
    if (deviceAddress[i] < 16) Serial.print("0");
    Serial.print(deviceAddress[i], HEX);
  }
}

// function to print the temperature for a device
String printTemperature(DeviceAddress deviceAddress)
{
  float tempC = sensors.getTempC(deviceAddress);
  if (tempC < 10)
    return "0" + (String)tempC;
  else
    return (String)tempC;
}

// function to print a device's resolution
void printResolution(DeviceAddress deviceAddress)
{
  Serial.print("Resolution: ");
  Serial.print(sensors.getResolution(deviceAddress));
  Serial.println();    
}

// main function to print information about a device
void printData(DeviceAddress deviceAddress)
{
  Serial.print("Device Address: ");
  printAddress(deviceAddress);
  Serial.print(" ");
  printTemperature(deviceAddress);
  Serial.println();
}

void loop(void)
{ 
  if (devicesFound == 0)
  {
     Serial.println("No devices found.");
     return;
  }

  sensors.requestTemperatures();

  String sent = "";

  // print the device information
  for (int i = 0; i < devicesFound; i++)
  {
    sent += printTemperature(devices[i]);
    if (i != devicesFound - 1)
      sent += " ";    
  }

  Serial.println(sent);
}
```

Comment: A trivial change, but I think it's cleaner:  Where you are adding spacing to the string, I'd use `if (i) sent += " ";`  as a statement *before* the statement adding the reading to the string, instead of the statement you currently have after

Answer (score 3):

With 12 bits precision, DS18B20 may take up to 750 ms converting a temp.

Try using async reading, so you don't have to wait for the end of the process.

First you ask for a reading, later your read it

```
    DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
    ...
    sensors.setWaitForConversion(false);  // makes it async
    sensors.requestTemperatures();
    sensors.setWaitForConversion(true);
    ...
    // Do something else while temp is been reading by the sensor
   ...
   float temp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
```

Comment: Does the `getTempByIndex` function build in the  wait-for-complete or are you assuming your "do something else" section is longer than a conversion?

Answer (score 2):

I would start by changing this section:

```
String sent = "";

// print the device information
for (int i = 0; i < devicesFound; i++)
{
  sent += printTemperature(devices[i]);
  if (i != devicesFound - 1)
  sent += " ";    
}

Serial.println(sent);
```

This section should read and print the temperature directly instead of creating a string. The string handling is a large overhead and it does not allow Serial (UART) to work very much in parallel if the buffer is filled. The printTemperature() function is using a lot of strings (and heap operations).

Otherwise you have done what is possible; 1) reduce the conversion resolution (9-bits is minimum), 2) use single conversion request command to all sensors.

The alternative is to use alarm triggers and only read sensors with alarms.

Comment: like that http://pastebin.com/NubeaW4M ?

Comment: What are the results of that? I did some tests and it is possible to issue a conversion request, read and print the results from 48 sensors at 9-bits resolution and 14 sensors at 12-bits resolution (per second).

Comment: delay is still the same

Comment: Can you scale it down to a single sensor and measure the conversion request and reading of scratch pad? We need to isolate the issue in the library that you are using.

Comment: So, I changed my sketch this way: http://pastebin.com/7EADdVAu, and it shows that around 110ms has passed while reading one sensor.

Comment: For 5 sensors it now shows values around 163ms, that's strage, it was bigger when I ran it earlier.